# Ubuntu 18.04 startup list freeze

Tags: boot, startup

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04. When I try to launch it, the list that shows on startup freezes in random places.
So all I see is:

[ OK ] something

[ OK ] something

...

[ OK ] something

and it just won't move forward.

I tried updating the graphic drivers, but that didn't help.

Help me please, guys.

Comment: Question is unclear, please add more information.

Comment: What information? Have the same problem, probably with nvidia card